# Create all the possible words from a list of character for a given length that starts with a given character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to create all the possible word list from a list of characters for a given length that starts with a given character.

Eg:

```
char_list = a,b,c
min_len = 2
max_len = 3
```

**Update:**

```
start with = c
```

so the fucntion should return something like this:

```
ca, cb, cc, cab, cac, cba, cbc...
```

How would I do this in python? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: None of these start with 'c', though. Can you clarify your desired output?

Comment: @Eithos Sorry my bad. :)

Comment: Is 'aaa' an acceptable output?

Comment: @Eithos Yes. I forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: Please take a look at my recent edits ;). Does it give the output you were expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You create a product object using the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) class from the standard library

```
import itertools

[''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(char_list, repeat= 2) if i[0].startswith('c')]
['ca', 'cb', 'cc']

[''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(char_list, repeat=3) if i[0].startswith('c')]
['caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```

To generate a word list for range of numbers use a `generator function`

```
def generate_word(chars_list, my_char, min_len, max_len):
    for i in range(min_len, max_len+1):
        for j in itertools.product(chars_list, repeat=i):
            if j[0].startswith(my_char):
                yield ''.join(j)

for word in generate_word(char_list, 'c', 2, 4):   
    print(word)
```

**Output**

```
ca
cb
cc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
caaa
caab
caac
caba
cabb
cabc
caca
cacb
cacc
cbaa
cbab
....
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need to create word list from min_len to max_len as in if  min_len is 4 and max_len is 8, then create word list of length 4 to 8. I hope I was clear.

Comment: @Aamu This does exactly what you want

Comment: I am getting this error: `[''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(char_list, 2)]
NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined`. And how do I set the character to start with?

Comment: @Aamu you need to import `itertools` module

Comment: @Michael9 If you notice, none of your outputs does something like `cba`. That's because your results come in sorted order, so it's always going to be `a` before `b`, before `c`.

Comment: @Eithos As you've noticed this is before and after OP edited his post.

Comment: @Michael9 I did. But it's still the same. Check his edit history. He still has examples like `aba` in his original post (which means `b` came before `a`). So it still applies. _And_... you haven't set it up so that `a` (or `c`, given the update) is always the starting character.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a program that uses a similar technique to Eithos's code. It creates a generator so you can get the words one at a time, if you want. The generator code will work on Python 2.6, and later, but you'll need to change the `print` for Python 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools

def word_generator(chars, start_with, min_len, max_len):
    for i in range(min_len - 1, max_len):
        for s in itertools.product(chars, repeat=i):
            yield start_with + ''.join(s)    

for word in word_generator('abc', 'c', 2, 4):
    print word
```

**output**

```
ca
cb
cc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
caaa
caab
caac
caba
cabb
cabc
caca
cacb
cacc
cbaa
cbab
cbac
cbba
cbbb
cbbc
cbca
cbcb
cbcc
ccaa
ccab
ccac
ccba
ccbb
ccbc
ccca
cccb
cccc
```

If you want the words in a list rather than one at a time, you can do:

```
word_list = list(word_generator('abc', 'c', 2, 4))
```

Comment: Nice. I often overlook the usefulness of generator functions!

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you want, I think:

I made a mistake earlier when I thought `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` would do the trick. Michael's post (which originally used `permutations`) made me reflect on my choice, so I started re-working the code. I actually got it working, but I quickly realized it was not the right tool for the job. Then I realized what you really needed is `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

minLen = 4
maxLen = 8
sChar = 'a'
print [sChar + ''.join(i) for x in range(minLen-1, maxLen) 
    for i in product(['a','b','c'], repeat=x)]
```

But if you try a smaller input to test:

```
minLen = 2
maxLen = 3
```

you get:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc']
```

We can also use `c` (per the updated post):

```
minLen = 2
maxLen = 3
sChar = 'c'

['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```